# Kubectl server and client versions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I've read that Kubectl is the client version and that the Kubernetes API Server of the Kubernetes Cluster is the server version...but I still don't really understand this. Where is this client version? is it on the control plane?   ..and do client and server versions actually both mean "kubectl" but in 2 different places.
My client version says 1.23  and my Server version says 1.18.20...but when I do `kubectl get nodes` it says that the nodes are on 1.18.9
so basically what I think I'm asking is... do BOTH "client" and "server" versions both relate to the kubectl version?

Comment: ...and if I said kubernetes version and kubectl version are actually the SAME thing...how wrong would I be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we run
`kubectl version`, we get information details for server and client.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5+k3s1", GitCommit:"405bf79da97831749733ad99842da638c8ee4802", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-18T00:43:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.5+k3s1", GitCommit:"405bf79da97831749733ad99842da638c8ee4802", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-18T00:43:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Here, `Server Version` represents version of Kubernetes control plane. Control plane includes `api-server`, `etcd`, various controllers etc.

`Client Version` represents Kubectl tool's version. Kubectl is a client tool to interact with control plane.

Kubectl can exist indepedent of Kubernetes cluster.

According to [kubectl doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/#before-you-begin)

> You must use a kubectl version that is within one minor version difference of your cluster. For example, a v1.23 client can communicate with v1.22, v1.23, and v1.24 control planes. Using the latest compatible version of kubectl helps avoid unforeseen issues.

In your case, it seems your server version is far behind of client version.

Comment: I would say that the statement from the official docs is a bit harsh. It probably should be SHOULD instead of MUST.  In any case you should strive for client version >= server version. The other way around is definitely not a good idea. But having a client version of say `1.28` and a server version of say `1.24` should not worry you. I wouldn't  - in such situation - bend over backwards to find an old kubect `1.24` or `1.25` to install on my workstation or in my CI runner. Just my 2c.